# Kentico 10 Contact activity logged against previously logged out user

Tags: kentico

We have a Kentico 10 website using custom WIF authentication.  That is all working fine.  I can see that the authenticated user details match what is expected.

I tried enabling the online marketing - contact tracking and then discovered that even though I had logged out with one account and then logged in with another account the new user's activity was being logged as if the first user had performed it.

The only that works reliably is using a delete cookie plugin in chrome which isn't a good solution for production.

I tried expiring the existing cookies for the domain and then found after logging out and back in again with a new user that all the new activity was being logged as public anonymous user.

[image: Anonymous contact activity]

Is there anything I can add to signout or login to ensure that the correct Contact is being tracked against.  Different users should be able to use the same browser logging out and back in again without this contact activity going against the wrong person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contact cookie is stored per user account on a computer.  So if you're simply logging in and out of Kentico this activity will not change your contact cookie.  Kentico sees you as the same contact even though you are authenticating with a different user account.

Kentico Contacts and Users are not synonymous although they can have a link to one another.  So I'd expect if the user account with linked with a contact you may see different activity for that particular contact.  The only way a contact is linked to a user account is if one of the 3 activities happen:

- Registers on a website
- Signs in with a user account
- Fill in customer data while making a purchase

So even though you're doing #2, I'm guessing something unique is happening since you're doing some testing on the local machine.  [Check out the documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/on-line-marketing-features/managing-your-on-line-marketing-features/contact-management/working-with-contacts#Workingwithcontacts-Linkingcontactswithuseraccounts) about contacts and linking to user accounts.  To test or see if a user is linked to a contact, go to Contact Management, manage a contact and click on the Membership>Users tab.  If see a user account linked to the contact then that contact is linked.  If you don't see one then that particular contact is not linked and you'll experience the issues you're explaining.

Comment: Apparently Kentico uses CurrentContact cookie which stores the GUID of the contact related to the current site visitor and this cookie is used to track activities on the website.  I find it a bit strange that it's not being cleared out if a user signs out of the website, and then recreated on login but was advised I could implement that if I wanted that behaviour. Thanks for your detailed response.